# PostgreSQL unable to run after process kill

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, shell, centos6

I'm developing an installer in Java, which suppose to install PostgreSQL 9.4.5 automatically in Centos 6 Linux OS. 
Also, the installation (the Java code) is responsible for creating new system user for the postgres and then registering and starting the PostgreSQL service as a postgres service:

```
`service "pgsql_service_name" start`
```

I have notices that if this process was killed using: 
`kill -9 "pgsql_pid"`
 it won't be able to recover using 
`service "pgsql_service_name" start`
 until deleting `postmaster.pid` file or `reboot` the system.

Now, the interesting part is what happening afterwards: after deleting the postmaster.pid file, I started Postgres service again using `service "pgsql_service_name" start` this time from the Linux  **shell**, only this time when I killed the process again using `kill -9 "pgsql_pid"`, the same `service "pgsql_service_name" start` command has managed to run successfully from shell and overwrite the `postmaster.pid` file automatically.

Why do you think this inconsistently between starting the process from Java code (the installer), and between killing it (or running it back) from Linux shell is happening? 

 Is there any better solution than deleting the `postmaster.pid` file at first time when this issue occur?

Comment: This is why you should always just do a normal kill before doing a kill -9.  This allows the process to shut down properly.

Comment: Why do you use `kill`? To stop the postgres server never use the kill command, but  `service postgresql stop`

Comment: I'm not intentionally doing kill to stop the process, this is actually a test for finding bugs in my installer. I just want my machine to be able to deal with such situation.